# React idiomatic way to update Map object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class.

I have a state like this:

```
{
    rows: new Map([])
}
```

With each row representing an entry in a table.
I'd like to update each row independently and asynchronously in a thread-safe manner.

What is the idiomatic React way to perform a setState when each modification is something like this (assume "fooId" has already been inserted into the Map):

```
const rows = this.state.rows;
const row = rows.get("fooId");
row.status = '75%';

this.setState({
    rows: rows
});
```

Comment: Everything in JS is threadsafe as there is only one thread . Updating a Map (or any other collection) in an immutable way is always difficult as you have to clone the whole Map which might cause lags

Comment: That's your only way of doing it with React, though, so you have no options. And that's assuming it causes latency issues (it might not).

Comment: Interesting question...may i ask for my personal knowledge...why do you choose `Map` approach instead of `Object`?

Comment: @NikkoKhresna I'm primarily a backend java / kotlin dev so that might explain it alone lol, but I was under the impression that Map is a better fit when you want to preserve insertion order.

Comment: Map is also a better fit if you don't have string or symbol keys, as objects will coerce keys to strings.

Comment: @DanPantry good point. I'm currently using string keys, but I could actually consider using an object because their is an original immutable object per row that makes as much sense as a key as does the sub-property of it that I'm currently using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be to use the functional `setState()` since you're updating an existing value rather than replacing it wholesale.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const nextRows = new Map(prevState.rows)
  // Creating a new Map this way does not clone the original data
  // This means that any update to an object in the map will update the previous map.
  // To avoid this, we create a new object using object spread and assign the updated value there.
  // This has the benefit of reducing memory allocations as well, if performance is your concern.
  // Though it should not be until you have proven it to be a concern.
  const nextEntry = {
    ...nextRows.get('fooId'),
    status: '75%'
  }
  return { rows: nextRows.set('fooId', nextEntry) }
})
```

This is made a little easier with ImmutableJS:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  rows: prevState.rows.update('fooId', entry => ({ ...entry, status: '75%' }))
}))
```

Also, just need to contradict what @Jonas said: When you clone a map, it only clones the mapping between a key and a value of the map. It does not clone the values of the map. That means that the memory consumption required is a lot lower than you might think.

If you're sure that you won't use the old map or *any of the objects referenced in the old map*, you could even do away with creating a new object using object-spread and you would only shoulder the impact of copying the key/value mapping (and creating a new object). This could lead to some really confusing bugs if you're wrong (and it would be very easy to be wrong) so I would stick to the immutable thing.

If this *really* becomes a performance issue, you could structure your data in a different way to have even fewer allocations on change.

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be `return { rows: nextRows.set('foodId', nextEntry); }`? Would it be better to do `return { rows: new Map([...prevState.rows, ...nextRows]) };` i.e. A Map merge? I'm not trying to prematurely optimize, but to just know the most idiomatic way. I'm primarily a backend java / kotlin dev having to rapidly learn React, and javascript Google results tend to be quite outdated. Googling the javascript Map class is particularly frustrating since the map function drowns it out I appreciate your insight.

Comment: You're correct about the return statement. You're potentially correct about `new Map`, although way you wrote it means you would have to write this something like: `new Map([...prevState.rows, ...new Map().set('fooId', {...prevState.rows.get('fooId'), status: '75%' })])` which I'm not sure is cleaner.  The way I've written is good enough to be idiomatic until you encounter perf issues (assuming you do).

Comment: As for documentation on React: Nothing written here is new and the React documentation is generally speaking correct on Google. The only real changes I can think of that aren't backwards compatible would be the ones to lifecycle methods (where a couple were marked unsafe).

Comment: Well I would still use a factored out cloned map on multiple statements so it wouldn't be all on one line like that. I tested it the non-merge way, now I'm testing the merge way, but looks like it should work either way, just wanted to know how the pros skin their cats.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't call myself a pro. I'd do it the first way until I encountered performance issues or until I found myself doing increasingly complex updates or needing to reuse the values of the map across many components.

Comment: Regarding documentation, I don't mean React in general, but more the problem of updating rows in a data structure. Most React stuff I see has to do with setting single properties.